# Posting a php value from a html table without input field to database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to post a td from a form.

this is my td...

`<td class="product'.$id.' " name="qnty" value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</td>`

since that has no input field, how i will post that value?

Because i am trying to post it like this, and it is not working.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_post'])){

$fabric=$_POST['fabric'];
$size=$_POST['size'];
$qnty=$_POST['qnty'];

$ins_sql = "INSERT INTO orders (fabric,size,product_quantity) 
            VALUES ('$fabric', '$size' , '$qnty')";
if ($conn->query($ins_sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " ;
}
$conn->close();
}
```

The rest of the posts are from dropdowns and they are working fine.
Why this is not working?

> Error: Undefined index: qnty

Comment: `<td>` are **NOT** form fields, have no `name` attribute, and are **NOT** submitted with a form. And you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: i know, this is only test

Comment: @MarcB this is not duplicated! i know what is a Undefined variable, i just was getting Undefined index : qnty because it was not a input name and just a td tag with the name`qnty`

Comment: Yes, it's a dupe. The specifics may be different from person to person, but the core reason is ALWAYS the same.

Answer (score 2):

Value will not work outside of form elements. You can make an input field and disable editing.

Or you can instead a hidden input.

```
 <td><input type="hidden" name="qnty" value="'.$value.'"/>'.$value.'</td>
```

If didn't understand the issue correctly it is because there is missing code here.

Comment: i used the input field inside of the <td>. thx  for this help man.

Comment: makes sense and gets the desired outcome. Np